# ClientServer App Java

Tags: java

Друзья просьба помочь понять почему не компилируется код сервера

Server:

```
import java.net*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnChatServer {





public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
    System.out.println("Server has started. Waiting for connection");
    int count = 1;



        while (true) {

            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client has connected " + (count++));


            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String outmessage = sc.nextLine();
            String inmessage = din.readUTF();
            dout.writeUTF(outmessage);

            System.out.println("Client: " + inmessage);
            System.out.println("Me: " + outmessage);


            din.close();
            dout.close();


            clientSocket.close();


        }
        //serverSocket.close();


    }
```

}

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnChatClient {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8000);
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outd = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream ind = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    String inmessage = ind.readUTF();
    System.out.println("Server: " + inmessage);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String outmessage = sc.nextLine();
    outd.writeUTF(outmessage);
    System.out.println("Me: " + outmessage);
    clientSocket.close();
    outd.close();
    ind.close();
}

}
```

Консоль:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: 
bind
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:469)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:458)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:374)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:260)
at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:151)
at OnChatServer.main(OnChatServer.java:13)
```

Comment: Вам какие то ошибки показывает?

Comment: дополнил топик, в конце

Comment: Код-то компилируется у вас, а при запуске выдает ошибку, что ваш порт 8000 уже занят каким-то другим приложением

Comment: верно) все заработало, но теперь не видно сообщений

Comment: если сообщения не видно - значит ошибки нет

Comment: я о том, что методы system.out.println не выводят сообщения)